# Joomla 3 onContentAfterSave not work backend

Tags: development, plugin, joomla-3.3.x, plugin-events

I want use onContentAfterSave in Joomla backend but it's not working.
My code this is:

```
class plgContentTest extends JPlugin
{

public function onContentAfterSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
{
    $option = JRequest::getVar('option');

    if($option=='com_content'){

        echo 'Test';

     }

   }

}
```

onContentAfterSave isn't working on backend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486746/joomla-3-x-oncontentaftersave-not-triggering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing on save, then echo'ing out something may never be seen as almost certainly a redirect is triggered after the save. So try adding an exit; to double check that it really isn't firing :

```
class plgContentTest extends JPlugin
{
    /**
    * Loads the application object
    *
    * @var    JApplicationCms
    * @since  3.2
     */
    protected $app = null;

    public function onContentAfterSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
    {
        $option = $this->app->input->get('option');

        if ($option=='com_content')
    {
            echo 'Test';
            exit;
        }

    }

}
```

Note that JRequest is deprecated and you can now inject in the Joomla application object by declaring it as a protected property.

Comment: For me using 3.4.7, it only works when the $article is passed by value ($article) and not by reference (&$article) like mentioned in the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Check following things:

- Plugin class name should be: `plgContentTest`
- Plugin class should extend `JPlugin` class
- Plugin filename should be: `test.php`
- Plugin file should be in: `/plugins/content/test`
- Plugin xml definition filename should be: `test.xml`
- Plugin xml definition file should be in: `/plugins/content/test`
- Plugin should be installed and enabled

#### Few other tips:

You should check context, not a direct request:

```
if ($context != 'com_content.form') {
    return true;
}
```

You can find sample content plugin here: [/plugins/content/joomla](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/content/joomla/joomla.php)

You should define article variable like this `$article` not this `&$article`.

Also it would be nice for you to provide directory structure of your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Most problems with Content plugins are caused by the plugin name. If it is not correctly named and installed, Joomla cannot find it and call *onContentAfterSave*.

Taking **finder** plugin as example:

- It is installed in plugins/content/finder folder.
- Plugin is named finder.php
- The class is PlgContentFinder (extends JPlugin)
- It has onContentAfterSave function